# Add class to all elements that mouse hovered while mouse clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three boxes:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.selected,
div:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

And i would like to click in one of the boxes, and while i'm with the mouse clicked and move to other boxes the div will have the "selected" classes add to it. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI `$.selectable()` does this well https://jqueryui.com/selectable/

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable();
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
}

#selectable li {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I don't think jquery-ui selectable is the exact functionality he wanted, probably better to check events "click" and "mouseenter" and make it be self, it's pretty simple.

Comment: @Michael Coker The same thing can be done without Jquery and with pure CSS then why not that.?

Comment: That's exactly that! Thank you @MichaelCoker

Comment: @AlesTrunda it is what OP was looking for.

Comment: @Chirag it's not the same, you can't do this with just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.choice').click(function() {
$(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

div:hover {

background: red;
}

.selected {
background: red;
border: 3px solid green;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choice">A</div>
<div class="choice">B</div>
<div class="choice">C</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove the class `selected` upon mouse click using jQuery `toggleClass()` method.

If you permanently want to add class `selected` to the element then use `addClass()` method instead.

```js
$(function(){
  $("div").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.selected,
div:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','div',function(e){
     $(this).toggleClass('sel');
});
```

Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/hrvn8y1d/

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question then you want something like below which will be a pure CSS way. Just add one more property in your CSS.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}


 div:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
 }    
div:focus {
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
 }
```

```html
<div tabindex="1">A</div>
<div tabindex="2">B</div>
<div tabindex="3">C</div>
```